# Email HTML template <form> not working

Tags: html, forms, security, email, internet-explorer

I'm sending **HTML** mail built with **Freemarker** from my webapp. In the email, there is a button inside a `<form>` tag as follows (fake URL):

```
<form action="http://192.168.123.456:23080/path/">
    <button style="border: 0; background-color: #003399; padding: 20px 40px; font-size: 18px; color: #FFFFFF; font-style: initial; cursor: pointer">ACCESS</button>
</form>
```

The form works on Google Chrome, even GMail on Chrome as well, but it does not work inside Outlook or from IExplorer (tested in IE11). When you click on the button nothing happens.

Are there any security constraints about it?

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of email clients do not support forms in HTML formatted email.

It isn't clear if the restriction is for security reasons or other reasons (or if it varies from client to client).

Either way, the restriction does exist. You should generally just include a link in the email that points to a regular HTTPS hosted page containing a form.

Comment: The problem is that if I open the email in an external windows in IE11 (as Outlook suggests) does not work as well, so, apart there is a non-support issue, what is occurring with IE11?